# grub doesn't appears after first reboot

Tags: grub2, windows-7

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 13.04 on Lenovo ThinkCenter with installed windows 7 from live CD. Everything seems ok but after first reboot from Ubuntu Grub doesn't appears and instead only windows 7 is loading. What can be wrong?

Thanks!

UPDATE:
As Srivatsa Kanchi sad I just had repair grub with following commands:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

It's give me list of partions where I should select with Linux and mount with:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda4 /mnt
```

Where sda4 my Ubuntu partition. Next fix grub:

```
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
```

That's all. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GRUB should be installed on the /dev/sda (for example) and not in any of its partition

Answer (score 0):

the answer given by Srivatsa Kanchi is correct but, if you want to come back to Grub Boot loader from the Windows i suggest you use this Software...
http://www.ubuntugeek.com/use-the-windows-bootloader-to-dual-boot-windows-vista-and-ubuntu.html